# Adding a basic auth to a http request in REST client

Tags: http, rest

if I want to access a password protected URL . how do I add the authentication information in a REST client . ie how do I add a username , password to the request .

should it be like

```
url?username=aasas&password=saas
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the information in the HTTP "Authorization" header and use "Basic" authorization. The RFC is here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617. There is a bunch of similar questions on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-basic-authentication. Wikipedia has a short introduction: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication